# Build chatbot for education purporse

Tags: nlp, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I try to build pretty simple chatbot which gonna be useful for kids as education tool.

As an example:

- *Bot*: Where do you live?
- *Expected answer*: I live in [Chicago].
- *Bot*: Where is [Chicago]?
- *Expected answer*: It's in Illinois.

And so on..

The main purpose on this bot is check does kid understand simple questions.

Firstly, I hard-coded list of expected answers.

But I thinks I can use for it tool like dialogflow?

Is it smart enough to use that powerful tool for this case?

Comment: Hmm using a model as chatbot contains the risk of false answers behaviour of the bot. Isn't this a problem especially for education?

Comment: Have you taken a look at Kore.ai? they have a very easy way to build chatbots, you can create an account and use their developer bot builder here: https://bots.kore.ai/botbuilder/login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really broad question, but yes, Dialogflow's Natural Language Understanding engine is certainly powerful enough to be trained with some example answers and extrapolate some other similar ones. It is not perfect, but is better than trying to hard-code and match every possible answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm re-launching this topic because I was confronted with the same case.
After several days of coding, I came to the conclusion that it's actually not so trivial to code a chatbot!

I finally opted for a chatbot creation solution ([Botnation](https://botnation.ai/en/))...

If you want to get a bot with advanced features, I recommend you to set up such a base rather than starting from 0.